# JS - Do sort in an array of strings as dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have the following array:

`let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"]`

when I execute

`datas.sort()`

he orders by alphabetical order, however, I must order first by the year and then by alphabetical order.

`["dez/2018", "jan/2019", "nov/2018", "out/2018", "set/2018"]`

Testing today I arrived at the following line of code:

```js
var datas = ["mar", "abr", "jan", "dez", "set", "mai", "jun", "out", "jul"];
var datas_corretas = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];
var result = [];

datas_corretas.forEach(function ordenar(element, index){
  var mes = datas.filter(function(valor){
  return valor == datas_corretas[index];
});
  result.push(mes[0]);
  for(element of result){
    if (element === undefined || element === null){
      result.pop(element);
    }
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

That way I can sort the data, but the problem is when I use it with the year

`var datas = ["mar/2018", "abr/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "set/2018", "mai/2018", "jun/2018", "out/2018", "jul/2018"];`

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"and then by alphabetical order"_?

Comment: So for a given input, what _exactly_ do you want the output to be? Are you actually trying to put these in date order? If so, then you'll need to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by first comparing the year part, and then the month part.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the dates and sort by year first, and then by the index of the month.

```js
var months = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"],
    datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"];

datas.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = a.split('/'),
        bb = b.split('/');
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || months.indexOf(aa[0]) - months.indexOf(bb[0]);
});

console.log(datas);
```

For a faster access, you could store the months as object.

```js
var months = { jan: 1, fev: 2, mar: 3, abr: 4, mai: 5, jun: 6, jul:7, ago: 8, set: 9, out: 10, nov: 11, dez: 12 },
    datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"];

datas.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = a.split('/'),
        bb = b.split('/');
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || months[aa[0]] - months[bb[0]];
});

console.log(datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

> however, I must order first by the year and then by alphabetical
>   order.
>
> `["dez/2018", "jan/2019", "nov/2018", "out/2018", "set/2018"]`

To achieve the expected result you can use `.sort()` twice, `.split()` at `"/"`, `.pop()` and `.shift()`

```
datas.sort((a, b) => a.split("/").pop() < b.split("/").pop() ? -1 : 0)
.sort((a, b) => a.split("/").shift() < b.split("/").shift() ? -1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

TIL you can pass a custom comparator to javascript's `sort` function. We can use this to write our own sorting logic by first comparing the years, then the months:

```js
let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"]
const orderedMonths = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];

datas.sort((a,b) => {
  var [montha,yeara] = a.split('/');
  var [monthb,yearb] = b.split('/');
  
  if (yeara > yearb) return 1;
  if (yearb > yeara) return -1;
  if (orderedMonths.indexOf(montha) > orderedMonths.indexOf(monthb)) return 1;
  if (orderedMonths.indexOf(monthb) > orderedMonths.indexOf(montha)) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

its very easy when converting the value to numbers and index.

Here se my example below.

```js
var datas_corretas = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];

var datas = ["mar/2018", "abr/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "set/2018", "mai/2018", "jun/2018", "out/2018", "jul/2018"];

var result = datas.sort(function(a, b){
// index of the month
var aMonth = datas_corretas.indexOf(a.split("/")[0]);
// convert the year to number
var aYear = parseInt(a.split("/")[1]);

var bMonth = datas_corretas.indexOf(b.split("/")[0])
var bYear = parseInt(b.split("/")[1])

return aYear - bYear || aMonth - bMonth;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I must order first by the year and then by alphabetical order.

Answers seem to all sort the month chronologically, so here's how to sort them alphabetically. Split in to month and year, then firstly compare years then compare months using *localeCompare*.

```js
let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"]

datas.sort((a, b) => {
  let [amon, ayr] = a.split('/');
  let [bmon, byr] = b.split('/');
  return (ayr - byr) || amon.localeCompare(bmon);
});

console.log(datas);
```